# Get date nearest to sysdate

Tags: sql, oracle, date, oracle11g

I would like to get per N the max(date) <= sysdate. If no dates in the past/today exist I want the min(date). So I do not want the absolute date nearest to sysdate.

Testdata

```
CREATE TABLE DATTEST (N NUMBER, D DATE);

INSERT INTO DATTEST (N,D) VALUES (1,TRUNC(SYSDATE-2000));
INSERT INTO DATTEST (N,D) VALUES (1,TRUNC(SYSDATE-1000));
INSERT INTO DATTEST (N,D) VALUES (1,TRUNC(SYSDATE+100));

INSERT INTO DATTEST (N,D)VALUES (2,TRUNC(SYSDATE));
INSERT INTO DATTEST (N,D)VALUES (2,TRUNC(SYSDATE+1000));


INSERT INTO DATTEST (N,D)VALUES (3,TRUNC(SYSDATE+1000));
```

So far I've got this. It gives the right results bus does two tablescans. I'm working on large tables and this query is called many times. I've been breaking my head converting this to a single table scan.

```
with nums as 
    (SELECT LEVEL num
     FROM DUAL
     CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 3
    ) 
select 
num
,(nvl((select  max(d)
    from dattest
    where d <= trunc(sysdate)
    and n = num),
    (select min(d)
    from dattest
    where d > trunc(sysdate)
    and n = num))
)
from nums;
```

Expected output

```
1   26-06-12
2   23-03-15
3   17-12-17
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using an aggregation, with some conditional logic?

```
select id,
       coalesce(max(case when d <= trunc(sysdate) then d end),
                min(d)
               )
from table t
group by id;
```

Comment: You should be using "<=":
select n,
       coalesce(max(case when d <= sysdate then d end),
                min(d)
               )
from dattest
group by n;